# Microsoft Monitoring Agent 2013 for standalone apps

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, monitoring, health-monitoring

As I understand it, the Monitoring Agent is designed to work with Web Sites. Now I want exactyle the same for my WPF standalone app. So is there a way to generate *.itrace-Files during the execution of a standalone application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! This feature is covered by the [IntelliTrace Collector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh398365%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#bkmk_install).